# Chaining Generics over ArrayLike Group

Tags: typescript, recursion, types

> Forgive me if my question sounds frazzled – I've been staring at this for a total of 12 hours :S Not even sure how to title this

**Background**

I'm looking to type a `compose` utility, which takes a rest parameter of `handlers` to loop through them. Its implementation looks like this:

```js
function compose(...handlers) {
    return async function (req, res) {
        let i=0, tmp, len=handlers.length;
        while (!res.finished && i < len) {
            tmp = await handlers[i](req, res);
            if (tmp instanceof Response) return tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, it continues until a `Response` is returned. Meanwhile, the `handlers` array is composed of "middleware" function(s) that are mutating the `req (Request-ish)` object.

**Goal**

The objective is to type `compose` (and middleware/handlers) in a way such that a group of middleware can (1) have its bare-requirements known *and* (2) collect all `Request` output forms so that a handler at the end of group is given all that information.

> [Demo Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitReturns=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzBAeAggGigJSgXigFUA7ASwHtiAVcgSWOAQGcIBjYC4legMwRM7oAfCPw4oEAB6NiAEyY4IARwCuEJsCgB+cQC4oxCADcEAbgCwAKFCQovfmUrCxaCdIhyFaePACGIABlSAGsIFFJiPngiIW0oAApCNxl5KAAJXzkAG1QIqJxYnVx9QxN4AEooEuMzKysbaAFKGnpGeBZ2QSpYgisoBKpkj1TMkDj4yX0qSrxY0aqDGoqhzwTJqDyEHBm54jGihdLayysAelOoAFpruutwaAzs1EGpFIVsZTUNMQ-VdWAegl4MoplhgUx9B8mGBKCwdlAjORSLILHdbGgVMAABYeDisXyMWS-L6aAjE-5QABkUAA3lAVCx4PpaIRGVAAL6ohpQNBgMDk75kz4U6l03x85m8sAc1FWWRsLK+YFQHgqYidShQP7wEAobrxcr6AAK8HIAFtSCw9UJUfLWIrlar1RxNZbHrIcvA9StUgLSYo-hohPEsfp3Z7rYaEUiUbcIm0eL5WNBaFLaX0NrISiozQAjY79BkIZHM1kIADaAHJkZWALqozlxhgIRPJuxl6I0jMlgw5-PwBuo85XG4nSzD2iLCCyKAAOVMdigYFNRmR0Gw9XusGRHogAHclWFZz73sLBQGSVhcK9hqfA-7Z4Dw6gjUqOL4sihH1SCrLxxdgF8UIoF8KAAAM-TAsEIGAFR4GIECELAqVIKsVhYU0YByClfQYB3HID2BFA-SwFCzwBMRfCYEB1SBZRoKYeEu0sfpgSUAA6cVpQIXwD1ITRtV1VM+WDcoG1uYc2JUUhlVzchsXAot4DAxCZzApSoIMcgQNkWR+M4JhTlYLFMmQJg0IwjYmClAB5PdDCZbddIIw90ExHEGFIfFCT9H8yPvQF4jYhimO7Hg6I4rj2KU5EoAAQjwAg2Oixl2ORSpmP6ViYLghDDD3RRoVhCB4krHhyHgXMdw8SssDpDQCQZfQABYAAYAGYOTEqBhxg1gM3ZKxBrHYdAOA+YIjATFwMgn9gVg+DEPAjFsVxLyCWnVDLHQ4hviwjtcPw-dXJInl3LW7zNvIwEqJo1gIpC-BYkyqAck0dDyGCUhoCS5R2JxXx5XadjkGAUqPq+iBK0qAAfGGoErStUX6UhwviOKIe+yp5tyxYCqhGFdpKysLSYJgIkQKBMahuqoAa2CISgNqAEYur-bKOKUyi+IEtQdW4DtRORjY0bi5KlOxnLFvywrCZYUqIiMD9Yup2raTpwCGZa1rWfZMShoki4qBxKAzQgAkoHIcLVqXU1cxyM0R1e8hyGlbF4BUU2jsIiBThMp52jOC4AD85iyLJbeMCgGS95zjuVchMSm4BLgaBR4mwSomCxROshnfNTYQZAZ2pJgCUtHgxht1g4OBBhKwUQxp3T2dyiDnksiYcgsHN4znddjW3wUPd+KxKBc0PGbyJUybpoaOUFUnp0NQQ9CzRhK1XBvVY8Ljn2UFGIRy1rLA0jEXfd33uAkFQNARGDdjH6VRBGfLR-2MwdJayjZ8B0NqAACiZQQDYgplAHEypLSW2CP4KwbpMi7ngPEDMa8N4lX2oyLAWEpRYEtLZeyCAsBBXolAcEoUWJZWSlxBcw5s653zimKUGYOYpTMD1C4dCVB53HimDsA026WH1iNC4AAhQgVAsB7lONpMCGCEAzwQkWLAYE8F8jsg5FSnDuHu3IAVbkCBTTwHbjw-ERZwLi0ZDPRu8koDyh4BEacUApEyJWh5PEG0iTTxAgoUCy5pxsHUF3Ixlh4EB2QRQ2hOcuEzh0QVAxFUUHmjQfEbBfJcHWTUQQ+ARDgqkPUOQrKeTIp8gXMwoprCBzsKgAAZTSDZQgAQAAiPIAjVJsoA7A2AbIbgoXrKwQj27GygVomcH4u5QFiRMrc8ToikDNGbPSG0sggGMfmUxLBwKqLAOo+RU55QxIgdALCIEsjAkBmMAumRlrnU8pdTx94wJwKYL-cJ-RIn0ImViU0cSfAJIoag8g8stk7IqP00wQA), showing my general progress w/ desired errors/behaviors in comments

So far, I've managed to get (2) working. This was a nice & briefly-satisfying start, but unfortunately it only helps & shows any errors within the final handler. Here's a [simplified playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzBAeAggGigJSgXigFUA7ASwHtiAVcgSWOAQGcIBjYC4legMwRM7oAfCPw4oEAB6NiAEyY4IARwCuEJsCgB+cQC4oxCADcEAbgCwAKFCQovfmUrCxaCdIhyFaePACGIABlSAGsIFFJiPngiIW0oAApCNxl5KAAJXzkAG1QIqJxYnVx9QxN4AEooEuMzKysbaAFKGnpGeBZ2QSpYgisoBKpkj1TMkDj4yX0qSrxY0aqDGoqhzwTJqDyEHBm54jGihdLayysAelOoAFpruutwaAzs1EGpFIVsZTUNMQ-VdWAegl4MoplhgUx9B8mGBKCwdlAjORSLILHdbGgVMAABa-L6aAi4-5QABkUAA3lAVCx4PoNPAIogoABfVENKAAMXI5EJ3wJnyJpIpPC5JRUAFsAEZbFm3WRsLK+YFQViwzRigCM+keshy8HQmJx-I0QlRctYCqVKuI3zFACYtZkdahOdyjQDTfLFdArTaAMwOp56nnu27nK43E6WMNULGkBQqnxsYBZMbA4AqeCGWRQbHe8iSiIQbMAA2DxZz9ysOU0kjEAG0NVg7U3fQBdVn3KAAEQgYvIYjgSFQDXIPCgkhNtzOF1oiyLUAAcqY7FAwPByEZkdBsPVOzBkU6AO5elALlapYM-N1YXCvYbvN1iBeA7W6lAABUVHF8WVPsVJ2CTpGZoWtAPAqMQnSUMq+Ywiw6Dngo+6yEeJ6jEIdatlgaQDgeOTHsCKCDsgepoCIQjxAAdNRiqIBCUB1tRlGYOkrblAGTrwKi04roY87Fhi2Jljm-ZSlAiCkCYxBYLOa4bluUDFmkEBZFkrp-BoxZWCBXowdamg8JqsB4RABFhIJhoacA2EqWpwZAbutjKap6l4leVkkuSUBYrZ5C0sA9LEIyMqRmGJAqmKYoeJowD9iwYGkLWPC+KQWQZhAPHVlA5CYmAmJiBFcEQPEjZQM2UCGVg8TAkoYLqPCZJVhAmg5cAeX4jBYpFSVtpYJVQLKHVTANX0UA1ZRPkuWI41UmYUCjWGAB6i0VSlWQKFKrC+LNikauWcmbnKCgCQawmHhcFKzdETJQLIvjAL4VhMuU3GWDpSrgZBHDQWgrCsBAYDACgLzuKsl58lZFFYhxb7dOxCJIiiVi-f9gPxK17UvUAA) that demonstrates this.

I'd argue (1) is just as important – if not more – because it would guarantee that something like `isAppOwner` can only succeed if something beforehand provisioned the `AppRequest` (or `Request & { app: IApp }`) ahead of it.

I've *accidentally* had (1) working. In other words, TS threw type errors on the middleware(s), but for inconsistent reasons.

**Chaining Requirements Visual**

Nothing new here, but offering a diagram of how I'm hoping this can work using the same example functions:

```
compose(
  // I take/need any `Request` (aka, no pre-existing data requirements)
  // I return/provide/guarantee an `AuthenticatedRequest`
  // ~> receives `Request` (bare/initial form)
  ({}) as Middleware<Request, AuthenticatedRequest>,

  // >>>  req === AuthenticatedRequest

  // I take/need any `Request` (aka, no pre-existing data requirements)
  // I return/provide/guarantee an `AppRequest`
  // ~> receives `AuthenticatedRequest` (via previous)
  ({}) as Middleware<Request, AppRequest>,

  // >>>  req === AuthenticatedRequest & AppRequest

  // I need both `AuthenticatedRequest` and `AppRequest`
  // I provide no further changes/mutations to the `req`
  // ~> receives `AuthenticatedRequest & AppRequest` (via previous)
  ({}) as Middleware<AuthenticatedRequest & AppRequest>,

  // >>>  req === AuthenticatedRequest & AppRequest

  async (req, res) => {
    // >>>  req === AuthenticatedRequest & AppRequest
  }
)
```

Finally, while it's probably not very helpful, I'm including all of my experimentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzBAeAggGigJSgXigFUA7ASwHtiAVcgSWOAQGcIBjYC4legMwRM7oAfCPw4oEAB6NiAEyY4IARwCuEJsCgB+cQC4oxCADcEAbgCwAKFCQovfmUrCxaCdIhyFaePACGIABlSAGsIFFJiPngiIW0oAApCNxl5KAAJXzkAG1QIqJxYnVx9QxN4AEooEuMzKwB6OqgbaHt4ASc0WIJ6xqg+qFcpFK8ffyDQ8MiEGKge-r6dROSPVIzs3Kno7ELxIZWFbGU1DTjigxro6rLKufmr2ssrZqJHajoGZjYOJyou2cs+vEqMtPFBMiA4vFJPoqJU8LFwVVztcQakofo8tNsHCEcQIUUkaUHnMALRkqxPcDQNayHLwFDAvagw6qdSaAgs47AP7xeDKGFYPlMfSHJhgSgsHFQIzkUiyCzWKkDFTAAAWnLZYg1JwAZFAAN5QFQseD6DTwCKIKAAXwVzwAYuRyNr2YpWbqDVAeE6SioALYAI2mtopllkbCyvj5UFYEs0foAjPoaXT0Cr1Uc2UIFeHWJHo7HiCc-QAmZOZWmoR3OzMabNWXP56CF4sAZnL63pLvrj0VtjSECyWRr7tdLqgesNqsHw7NwAtxCtId7pJJUBYYCjvkYoeecCQEAAchAIPJ0FhcAR2m96Ix4Cx2IJj6emMJRBzUQda5oCfd4HalX3ZAAHkVTAFVX0wcQr1eGhb0+R8nFA4BwOASCRD+XAmVScdf2RYk+2gZ8z06FxPwGUZAhCMJMWiQgdiWbCFBgAB3KMaM2OwsFoqBgJ2WgkSSJj0grVMeO2U5CQuSo-wA2xkNQ9CyOE7w-CoiYePoyEhPcUFWPYyZ8lobjOL4uJaB1YDBPIlMNnyCS8KJCopLKBVKVsfS+W4ciXSwKzhPHAhaB5PklH0AS9QABSjDhfCyFA+MFdQRXUcUiwgKVRTSlgoAAH2lWVZDyqBIvgcg-VIFgUCyiVoHymU5R7BsI3Yr0VGIRDiC9J0AyjdByPBABtABdC8fO-LVvyEeIADo5qjRBhSgQa5pm+gxS+aqsE6LBbPpICIAUiC32GqByn0NBQ0bVqW00Xwk1gNivLQdNfPSGcRy5Jqwxags4zBMtHoMt7q27HNfubf7fHbIGvLel61TB0Mck0SQSzEQbfBLLBoZxhNhrk6AABEID9ch0aCotIHYarvywZpyB4KA0e+lGoHIFUKe68hevgeIsbxrBeWUJKmClfUrHmUKZu9cgxATEtWwVa1yjcwiXgDchJAZP5GV0tFNPKEa4iSGE1eeSQFdbMQSE17WGaZlndyVdbqeAarxtHbaukl-pBn1kY1PGDj8no32FjsKnNuwLAw4Bfp9HicP5gGcjPJD6YAA0TPyABNHZ062qBM51fP-hThPU+EvbDKzgunrCGOcB1TPYmTu58PgZPylDVc1wW1VndsWXvICiaOTp3i8GCsReXCqUGvlK6Ibajrvi66ch3IfrhNlkaxrH0dJtHabVoWpaVrmgA1OK5W3Rvvd20TUFlgB9DmUOOzohGG86RM7c2So34REUs4Ag-thgUSDtRWudEGI6UgSPHixkoA8TMjoASf4ZKd0Jtzd+YEv5-AgfsKBYwYGaXgeRJBnEUFoJ2FZLBLkCKb2HEneOgJ9QqzBAoEeIMnTdgwMneInDKi+B4U6FAoNJ4IwzCfQR7CEgiO4dzWmXsoBSLkUI0Kotxbt36NLWWUAADUBAEytgACwKnmNaKwPdezPBvlkO+jAPaHy5NtAaeIRp-GTsQ0Eg1NJYFWvEHisJTrJx0Agkh1CjI52mHxPREcBIBXLhXFOOhBqECCdfW+sh77cEslgX44SFFpKYV3UplcnLJwuuRVSZCNKcTjmUyJVCJHILidEBJlSK4YJ8ibY2f5EkpyGT08pphUl9AaAkZO0z5hRNBDE6YtDTJtwUXM-ofSAqzN6GkjJWSoCrUcc4sIFlgJFJ-pMqAGyK6jPmDc8pOyzpIk1uQHImQRpWP6NM2STzFhPPmW07eHTUGrIBZsuw-TwW9N4lC9ZuyykR0ydkmaxy8kuLOVgVuw1oWIrud8hFIzO64vxVMxo2CnKmCAA). At the very bottom (`Validate`) I was trying out to do a recursive, conditional checker, using the current/head of the list (`U`) and passing in the remaining elements (`T`). Threw in the towel here.

Any & all help appreciated!